# Algorithm for concurrent access to resource(s) on database

Tags: database, algorithm, concurrency, locks

Some time ago we implemented a warehouse management app that keeps track of quantities of each product we have in the store. We solved the problem of concurrent access to data with database locks (select for update), but this approach led to poor performance when many clients try to consume product quantities from the same store. Note that we manage only a small set of product types (less than 10) so the degree of concurrency could be heavy (also, we don't care of stock re-fill). We thought to split each resource quantity in smaller "buckets", but this approach could lead to starvation for clients that try to consume a quantity that is bigger than each bucket capacity: we should manage buckets merge and so on...
My question is: there are some broadly-accepted solutions to this problem? I also looked for academic articles but the topic seems too wide.

P.S. 1:
our application runs in a clustered environment, so we cannot rely on the application concurrency control. **The question aims to find an algorithm that structures and manages the data in a different way than a single row**, but keeping all the advantages that a db transaction (using locks or not) has.

P.S. 2: for your info, we manage a wide number of similar warehouses, the example focuses on a single one, but we keep all the data in one db (prices are all the same, etc).

Comment: Pleas clarify what operations do you want execute in parallel? Select, Calculate and Update?

Comment: The main issue is related to update product quantities. For instance, currently we have one row for product "A" with quantity of 500. Clients update this quantity by subtracting some amounts. The order of magnitude of this subtraction may vary from less than 10 for each client to 100 or 200; but this case is less frequent, actually. We would look for some algorithm that is not strictly related to database lock management but to resource partitioning/merging in order to reduce the degree of concurrency on the single product record. Obviously clients shouldn't make the resource quantity negative

Comment: What's the problem that you try to solve with "select for update"? What RDBMS are you using? If you are not using the antiquated MySQL your RDBMS can give you lock-free consistent reads.

Comment: We use Oracle 10g. Actually issue is not related to the DBMS itself. When you begin a transaction that involves many tables, whether we want it or not, we must decide the policy about reading. If we don't lock rows, during the transaction other people could read a value that will be changed when transaciton ends (dirty read), because before subtracting we *have* to read the current value; further, the transaction could fail due to other circumstances (other products unavailable, no prices defined, and so on).

Comment: Read-only transactions should simply use Oracles snapshot isolation to get consistent and lock-free reads. Writers indeed need to lock but there should be few writes per row per second. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: The problem is that there could be a lot of writes in some moments, I cannot go in deep with business-specific requirements (this doesn't matter, however), but there could be also 20-30 writes on some products in the same second. Usually (98% of times) these parallel requests are for 3-4 pieces for each product type, but there could be someone demanding for 100 pieces (the worst case we detected was about 400). The resource partitioning on more rows still seems the best option to me, but the partition/merge strategies to be used are not clear at the moment.

Comment: Consider simply "logging" all writes by inserting their data into a log table. Reads must read the log table and apply the changes in-memory (or as part of the query). This makes writes almost completely scalable. You also need a periodic merge to remove the "change" rows and merge them back into the main data row. Hope it is clear what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The setup below will still work on a cluster if you use a queueing program that can coordinate among multiple processes / servers, e.g. [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

You can also use a simpler queueing algorithm that only uses the database, with the downside that it requires polling (whereas a system like RabbitMQ allows threads to block until a message is available).  Create a Requests table with a column for unique `requestId`s (e.g. a random UUID) that acts as the primary key, a `timestamp` column, a `respourceType` column, and an integer `requestedQuantity` column.  You'll also need a Logs table with a unique `requestId` column that acts as the primary key, a `timestamp` column, a `resourceType` column, an integer `requestQuantity` column, and a boolean/tinyint/whatever `success` column.

When a client requests a quantity of ResourceX it generates a random UUID and adds a row to the Requests table using the UUID as the requestId, and then polls the Logs table for the requestId.  If the `success` column is true then the request succeeded, else it failed.

The server with the database assigns one thread or process to each resource, e.g. ProcessX is in charge of ResourceX.  ProcessX retrieves all rows from the Requests table where `resourceType = ResourceX`, sorted by timestamp, and then deletes them from Requests; it then processes each request in order, decrementing an in-memory counter for each successful request, and at the end of processing the requests it updates the quantity of ResourceX on the Resources table.  It then writes each request and its `success` status to the Logs table.  It then retrieves all of the requests from Requests where `requestType = RequestX` again, etc.

It may be slightly more efficient to use an autoincrement integer as the Requests primary key, and to have ProcessX sort by primary key instead of by timestamp.

---

One option is to assign one `DAOThread` per resource - this thread is the only thing that accesses that resource's database table so that there's no locking at the database level.  `Worker`s (e.g. web sessions) request resource quantities using a concurrent queue - the example below uses a Java [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), but most languages will have some sort of concurrent queue implementation you can use.

```
public class Request {
  final int value;
  final BlockingQueue<ReturnMessage> queue;
}

public class ReturnMessage {
  final int value;
  final String resourceType;
  final boolean isSuccess;
}

public class DAOThread implements Runnable {
  private final int MAX_CHANGES = 10;
  private String resourceType;
  private int quantity;
  private int changeCount = 0;
  private DBTable table;
  private BlockingQueue<Request> queue;

  public DAOThread(DBTable table, BlockingQueue<Request> queue) {
    this.table = table;
    this.resourceType = table.select("resource_type");
    this.quantity = table.select("quantity");
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      Requester request = queue.take();
      if(request.value <= quantity) {
        quantity -= request.value;
        if(++changeCount > MAX_CHANGES) {
          changeCount = 0;
          table.update("quantity", quantity);
        }
        request.queue.offer(new ReturnMessage(request.value, resourceType, true));
      } else {
        request.queue.offer(new ReturnMessage(request.value, resourceType, false));
      }
    }
  }
}

public class Worker {
   final Map<String, BlockingQueue<Request>> dbMap;
   final SynchronousQueue<ReturnMessage> queue = new SynchronousQueue<>();

   public class WorkerThread(Map<String, BlockingQueue<Request>> dbMap) {
     this.dbMap = dbMap;
   }

   public boolean request(String resourceType, int value) {
     dbMap.get(resourceType).offer(new Request(value, queue));
     return queue.take();
   }
}
```

The Workers send resource requests to the appropriate DAOThread's queue; the DAOThread processes these requests in order, either updating the local resource quantity if the request's value doesn't exceed the quantity and returning a Success, else leaving the quantity unchanged and returning a Failure.  The database is only updated after ten updates to reduce the amount of IO; the larger MAX_CHANGES is, the more complicated it will be to recover from system failure.  You can also have a dedicated IOThread that does all of the database writes - this way you don't need to duplicate any logging or timing (e.g. there ought to be a Timer that flushes the current quantity to the database after every few seconds).

The Worker uses a SynchronousQueue to wait for a response from the DAOThread (a SynchronousQueue is a BlockingQueue that can only hold one item); if the Worker is running in its own thread the you may want to replace this with a standard multi-item BlockingQueue so that the Worker can process the ReturnMessages in any order.

There are some databases e.g. [Riak](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/dev/using/data-types/#Counters) that have native support for counters, so this might improve your IO thoughput and reduce or eliminate the need for a MAX_CHANGES.

You can further increase throughput by introducing `BufferThread`s to buffer the requests to the `DAOThread`s.

```
public class BufferThread implements Runnable {
  final SynchronousQueue<ReturnMessage> returnQueue = new SynchronousQueue<>();
  final int BUFFERSIZE = 10;

  private DAOThread daoThread;
  private BlockingQueue<Request> queue;
  private ArrayList<Request> buffer = new ArrayList<>(BUFFERSIZE);
  private int tempTotal = 0;

  public BufferThread(DAOThread daoThread, BlockingQueue<Request> queue) {
    this.daoThread = daoThread;
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      Request request = queue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if(request != null) {
        tempTotal += request.value;
        buffer.add(request);
      }
      if(buffer.size() == BUFFERSIZE || request == null) {
        daoThread.queue.offer(new Request(tempTotal, returnQueue));
        ReturnMessage message = returnQueue.take();
        if(message.isSuccess()) {
          for(Request request: buffer) {
            request.queue.offer(new ReturnMessage(request.value, daoThread.resourceType, message.isSuccess));
          }
        } else {
          // send unbuffered requests to DAOThread to see if any can be satisfied
          for(Request request: buffer) {
            daoThread.queue.offer(request);
          }
        }
        buffer.clear();
        tempTotal = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Workers send their requests to the BufferThreads, who then wait until they've buffered `BUFFERSIZE` requests or have waited for 100ms for a request to come through the buffer (`Request request = queue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`), at which point they forward the buffered message to the `DAOThread`.  You can have multiple buffers per `DAOThread` - rather than sending a `Map<String, BlockingQueue<Request>>` to the Workers you instead send a `Map<String, ArrayList<BlockingQueue<Request>>>`, one queue per `BufferThread`, with the Worker either using a counter or a random number generator to determine which `BufferThread` to send a request to.  Note that if `BUFFERSIZE` is too large and/or if you have too many `BufferThread`s then Workers will suffer from long pause times as they wait for the buffer to fill up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the application runs in a clustered environment, so the thread approach cannot be adopted (we thought to a distributed lock mechanism, but this should be the last option, for the related issues it brings). Instead, we would prefer a strategy on manipulating the data structure on the DB itself, not excluding locks at all. The tip about Riak seems interesting. However, I'm going to improve the question with these details. Thank you again!

Comment: @piero86 I've edited the top of my answer to address clusters